when i update flutter_inappwebview 6.0.0
hi i am beginner in flutter i have problem when update package  flutter_inappwebview 6.0.0  from flutter_inappwebview: ^5.8.0
return Observer(builder: (context) {
      return Stack(
        children: [
          wishListStore.isNetworkAvailable
              ? InAppWebView(
                  key: webViewKey,

                  initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                      url: Uri.parse(widget.mInitialUrl == null
                          ? 'https://www.google.com'
                          : widget.mInitialUrl!)),
                  initialOptions: options,
                  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                    webViewController = controller;
                  },
                  onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
                    log("onLoadStart");
                    setState(() {
                      isLoading = true;
                    });

and this error = The argument type 'Uri' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'WebUri?'.
flutter_inappwebview

This question is similar to: Uri Can't be assigned to webUri. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You need to change the Uri to WebUri

As per the flutter_inappwebview changelog from version 6.0.0-beta.10 they have replaced the usage of Uri type with the new WebUri type.
Now you have to use like :
WebUri(widget.mInitialUrl == null
                      ? 'https://www.google.com'
                      : widget.mInitialUrl!)


it is works But when I click on the link, I see a blank page without data!
